# Duplicate plots are output when using seaborn.objects with subplots in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am running the code in jupyter, which displays a plot figure. However, without `plt.show()`, the same plot is duplicated, so two plot figures are display. Why is this happening?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 3))

p = so.Plot(diamonds, x="carat", y="price")
p.add(so.Dots()).scale(y="log").on(ax1).plot()
p.add(so.Dots(), color="clarity").scale(color="crest").on(ax2).plot()
plt.show()
```

Output without `plt.show()`

[image]

Comment: Remember, `seaborn.objects` is a work in progress. The code works as expected when using `.subfigures`, as show in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#integrating-with-matplotlib). [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naUO2.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this because you're both returning the `Plot` from the cell and using the `matplotlib-inline` pyplot backend.

When a `Plot` object is returned from the last line in a Jupyter Notebook cell, it will be rendered and displayed in the cell output through Jupyter's [rich display](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display) system. You can also call `display(p)` to hook into the same mechanism.

Separately, because you're using the `matplotlib-inline` pyplot backend (implicitly; it is Jupyter's default), any pyplot figures created by the cell will be captured and added to the cell output.

These are completely different mechanisms and don't know about each other.

As you've noticed, adding `plt.show` to the end of the cell disables the first mechanism, because the `Plot` is no longer "returned" from the cell. It does not actually matter whether you call `plt.show` or anything else (although `plt.show` is a good one because it has no return value, so it doesn't add anything else to the cell output). You could also "catch" the final plot (e.g. `_ = p.add(...)`) or add a trailing semi-colon, similar to how you would [disable other cell outputs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/faq#why-is-something-printed-after-every-notebook-cell).

Alternatively, you could call `plt.close` to disable the second mechanism. But if you just made `plt.close` the final line of the cell, you wouldn't see any plots at all, for the reason given in the previous paragraph. You'd need to make sure to display the `Plot` too.

You might notice that the two images have different sizes / resolutions. The images that `Plot` generates through the first mechanism (rich display) use hi-dpi ("retina") scaling by default, so that is a factor to consider when deciding which you want to keep.

Comment: If you create a interactive plot, both an inline and interactive plot appear. If you capture the output with `;`, `_ =`, or `plt.show()`, the inline plot no long appears. The interactive figure window appears, but the is not populated with a plot.